# Best way to fill variables of an object between some fragments

Tags: android, object, android-fragments, android-activity

I need to fill a Custom Object with data obtained from differents fragments. One option is to do a parcelable object and pass it throught each fragment, but I think that is a better option to declare the object in the activity and access to it from each fragment without move data.

What it is the best option for this?

Comment: A singleton class maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface to communicate between your fragments and activities.

Android documentation explanation is pretty straight forward and with clear examples for what you need, check it here [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Basically you need to create an interface, declare it in your fragment and your activity should implement it. When you have the data in your fragment you can trigger that event in your activity passing the data and in your activity you will have the data to fill your custom object.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in a data `Fragment`, which uses `setRetainInstance(true)`. `setRetainInstance` controls whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation (such as from a configuration change).

In Activity class, instantiate the data fragment. It can then be shared across multiple fragments of same activity.

Example `data Fragment` class:

```
public class MyDataFragment extends Fragment {
    public static MyDataFragment newInstance() {
        return new MyDataFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Retain this instance so it isn't destroyed when MainActivity and MainFragment change configuration.
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }    

    // data shared across multiple fragments of same activity
    public String myData = null;
}
```

Example `Activity` class:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // common data fragment shared by multiple fragments
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MyDataFragment myDataFragment = (MyDataFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(MY_DATA_FRAGMENT);

    if (myDataFragment == null) {
        MyDataFragment dataFragment = MyDataFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, MY_DATA_FRAGMENT).commit();
    }
}

public static final String MY_DATA_FRAGMENT = "MY_DATA_FRAGMENT";
```

In various fragments, you can access the data fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // access data fragment
    final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    this.myDataFragment = (MyDataFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(MyActivity.MY_DATA_FRAGMENT);
}

private void function1 () {
    // read data from data Fragment
    String dataStr = this.myDataFragment.myData;

    // write data into data Fragment
    this.myDataFragment.myData = "test_string";
}

private MyDataFragment myDataFragment = null;
```